# Long table using kable - knit Word and "Repeat Header Rows" function

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I have very long tables and I would like to knit a word document using kable.

By default, "Repeat Header Rows" function is disabled and I hope to enable it, rather than clicking the button several times.

Any idea would be much appreciated. Thanks.

[image: long table]

Comment: I wonder if pander() has this functionailty.

Comment: `pixiedust` can mimic a longtable going into Word. It defaults to 25 rows per section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the ReporteRs package.

By default, when I use `addFlexTable` and `vanilla.table` function of ReporteRs, I can get what I wanted (Repeat Header Rows).

`addFlexTable(myDoc , vanilla.table(iris))`

Comment: However, ReporteRs is a kind of dead-end. Word file cannot be translated into markdown, LaTeX nor epub.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it with VBA in Word.

Press Alt + F11 and paste this script and run.

```
Sub RepeatTableHeadings()

  Dim tbl As Table

  For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
  Next tbl

End Sub
```